# phpunit error Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\TestSuiteSorter::reorderTestsInSuite must be an instance of PHPUnit\Framework\Test

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using

PHPUnit 9.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

and when i run phpunit why can i see the following error?

```
Argument 1 passed to PHPUnit\Runner\TestSuiteSorter::reorderTestsInSuite() 
must be an instance of PHPUnit\Framework\Test, 
instance of PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite given, 
called in /root/.config/composer/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php on line 207
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was because a file I was testing was requiring another file which was requiring files using relative url paths.

For example I could see this error with relative paths.

```
<?php

require_once 'fileOne.php';
require_once 'fileTwo.php';
```

but when i changed to these to absolute paths it fixed the issue

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/fileOne.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/fileTwo.php';
```

Moral of the story. don't use relative paths.